# Finding length of all strings in an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, size

```
dictionary = File.foreach('dictionary.txt').map { |line| line.split('\n') }
dictionary.each{|word|
    puts word.length
        if word.length == 5
            puts word
        end
}
```

It says the value for each |word| is only 1. Anyone have a clue why? Thanks.

Comment: `map { ... split('\n') }` should return array of arrays, each of subarrays with only one element (as the delimiter `\n` is at the end). You want `line.strip`, not `line.split`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re mapping a function that splits a line into lines to every line. Each line will contain one line, resulting in a one-element array. Maybe you meant `line.chomp`?

```
dictionary = File.foreach('dictionary.txt').map &:chomp
```